# .bash_profile path won't work with anaconda3

Tags: terminal, bash, path

Changed my .bash_profile and path now it's the following reads at each new terminal login:

```
-bash: conda: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found
```

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
(base) Me:~ myuser$

When chsh -s /bin/zsh entered:

```
-bash: chsh: command not found
```

Temporary Fix for simple command functions, but still missing full functionality:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

I've tried both [this fix][1] and another fix, and tried to reinstall anaconda3.

But my .bash_profile is now very complicated from conda:

```
 # added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer
    # >>> conda init >>>
    # !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
    __conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/myuser/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        \eval "$__conda_setup"
    else
        if [ -f "/Users/myuser/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
    # . "/Users/myuser/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"  # commented out by conda initialize
            CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
        else
            \export PATH="/Users/myuser/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
        fi
    fi
    unset __conda_setup
    # <<< conda init <<<
    export PATH=/Users/myuser/anaconda3/bin/python

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Yes, I'm a noob...

Comment: You have two conda  installations: the first one marked ```# added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer``` and a second one marked ```# >>> conda initialize >>>``` - so check which one is the real - the second one is in ```/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH``` - if this is true, then delete the first one - note the the ```opt``` folder in the second one. And you must decide which shell to use - if zsh, then install conda from zsh. A good installation will be observed in terminal by the word ```base``` before your shell prompt.

Comment: It appears that you forgot to include the address for the first fix you tried but did not work: "[this fix][1]".

Comment: Also, the line `export PATH=/Users/myuser/anaconda3/bin/python` is wrong; it should probably be `export PATH="/Users/myuser/anaconda3/bin/python:$PATH"`

Comment: Thanks, it was the second one:
/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
Now zsh is working as well.